# Junit Testing mock a service and filter results

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I want to test the following function (Junit test). I am using Mockito to mock Dynamodao service (It gets items from dynamodb). I am filtering the items based on the owner name.

```
owner = this.getUser(httpRequest);
List<MapData> result = this.dynamoDao.getAllRecords(TABLE_NAME, Regions.US_WEST_2);
List<MapData> result1 = result.stream().filter(x -> owner.equals(x.getOwner()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here MapData is a class which has Owner as a dynamodbattribute. I read about Mockito and realised that I would need it to mock the service.

```
@Mock
private DynamoDao dynamoDao;
```

How can I test this simple function? I could really use some help on how to proceed. How can I use "when" here? I tried going through sample codes online but did not understand much.

Answer (score 1):

So, the class under test has a method which includes the few lines of code you showed above. In addition, I assume, an instance of `DynamoDao` is injected into this class perhaps via a constructor.

Given those assumptions your test case might look something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private DynamoDao dynamoDao;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // create an instance of MapData which matches the behaviour expected of this test
        List<MapData> expectedResult = ...;

        when(dynamoDao.getAllRecords(re(TABLE_NAME), eq(Regions.US_WEST_2))).thenReturn(expectedResult);

        // now invoke your method i.e. the one from which the extract in your question is taken

        // now add assertions which match how you expect your method to behave when dynamoDao returns the expectedResult you created above 
    }
}
```

So, briefly:

- Annotate the class to ensure that the mock is initialised
- Inject the mock into the class-under-test
- Tell the mock to return some data which allows you to direct the mock's behaviour
- Call the method-under-test
- Assert that the method-under-test behaves correctly

Comment: Thank you. How do I address the result1 i.e. filter part? Result currently gives me paginatedscanlist reference and result1 has the actual data contents

Comment: Could you perhaps update your question to clarify this comment? Maybe show us your latest code after any changes you have made in response to the answers to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT mock your DynamoDB client**. Are you going to mock all DynamoDB methods to ensure that your mocking exactly implements DynamoDB behaviour with all minor details? Are you going to return exact return values that DynamoDB protocol returns? What if you are going to add transactions or optimistic locking? Will you mock these details as well and throw correct exceptions and return proper values?

Implementing an in-memory DynamoDB client is a big project and every time you make a tiny mistake you are in a world of pain. So instead of mocking it just use [existing in-memory DynamoDB from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html).

All you need to do is to make you DynamoDAO configurable, so you can pass any DynamoDB client to it like:

```
class DynamoDAO {
  public DynamoDAO(AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB) {
    this.dynamoDB = dynamoDB
  }

}
```

Then in your tests you can create embedded in-memory DynamoDB instance and use it as you want:

```
AmazonDynamoDB dynamodb = DynamoDBEmbedded.create().amazonDynamoDB();
DynamoDAO dao = new DynamoDAO(dynamodb);
// Write your tests here ...
```

**P.S.** If you are using Maven you need to add the following:

```
<!-- Local DynamoDB depends on sqlite4java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite4java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.392</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite4java-win32-x86</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.392</version>
    <type>dll</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite4java-win32-x64</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.392</version>
    <type>dll</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
    <artifactId>libsqlite4java-osx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.392</version>
    <type>dylib</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Local DynamoDB dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0.1</version>
    <scope></scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Repository for local DynamoDB -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dynamodb-local</id>
        <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<!-- Copy native libraries for sqlite to your project on build so you can access them -->
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includeScope>test</includeScope>
                    <includeTypes>so,dll,dylib</includeTypes>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you want to test if the filter expressions against dynamodb see @Ivan Mushketyk excellent answer.

Note i donot know anything about dynamodb or mockito.

If you want to test the code that uses dynamodb this is how i would do the testing:

Hide dynamodb specific code behind a **repository interface facade** and only use that repository in your code

```
interface IRepository {
   List<MapData> findMapData(...);
}

List<MapData> result1 = myRepository.findMapData(
         owner, TABLE_NAME, Regions.US_WEST_2)
```

There are two implementations for `IRepository` : one that calls dynamodb and one that simulates/mocks dynamodb.

I usually implement my mocks by creating a text-filename from the findXXX parameters and return the converted textfile/resourcefile content.

Example: the mocked myRepository.findMapData("smith", "customer", Regions.US_WEST_2) loads xml from file ...testdata/smith_customer_west2.xml which is converted to `List<MapData>` and  returned.

Use a human readable format for your simulation data that can be easily converterted to internal objectmodell. (i.e. xml, json, csv, ....)